# PyQt5 - QTime not changing values

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I wanted to create a simple timer that gets shown to the screen and was using QTime to track the amount of time passed. However when I create a time with QTime(0, 0, 0) it will always stay at the initial value and will never change.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime

time = QTime(0, 0, 0)
print(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))      # 00:00:00
    
time.addSecs(20)
print(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))      # Still 00:00:00 for some reason
```

Why is the above code not updating the time variable and is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a super simple fix to this.  `time.addSecs(20)` returns a value.  So do `time = time.addSecs(20)` instead.  That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtime.html#addSecs) the function signature is...

```
QTime QTime::addSecs(int s) const
```

So you need...

```
time = time.addSecs(20)
print(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name might be a bit counter intuitive, but the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs) is very clear about this.

It doesn't say that `addSecs()` "Adds `s` seconds to *this* object", but that it

> **Returns** a QTime object containing a time `s` seconds later than the time of **this** object"

<sup>(emphases mine)</sup>

Your `time` object does **not** change using `addSecs()`.

The **only** way to change a QTime instance is by using [`setHMS()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#setHMS).

If you want a convenience function that actually changes the time value for the *same* reference, you can do it by creating a new "patched" method at the very beginning of your code, right after the *first* PyQt import:

```py
def adjustSecs(time, s):
   new = time.addSecs(s)
   time.setHMS(new.hour(), new.minute(), new.second(), new.msec())

QTime.adjustSecs = adjustSecs

# ...

t = QTime.currentTime()

print(t) # shows current time

t.adjustedSecs(3600)

print(t) # shows previous current time plus an hour
```